# Coding a gradebook for education

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to code a gradebook in Google Sheets. I have coded a tab to import data from a different tab into a sheet with all standards combined. I then need to add the items under the same standard. However, I do not want it say 0 if there is no data in that cell. How do I get it to leave the cell blank unless there is data to calculate. I have used `=iferror(sum(S13:U13))` and `=iferror(sum(S13:U13),**)`.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What is the problem with your formulas? Why is [tag:google-apps-script] included?

Answer (score 3):

If it were me, I would adjust your formula to add all columns instead of summing them.  That way you can use an array instead of copying down the formula. The formula below will grade every row as long as there is data in A3:A.  If the student names (or another field) are in a different column then just change that reference to the column that will always have data for each row.  The reason for this is to limit the array to stop at the end of your data instead of calculating to the bottom of the sheet.

```
=Array_Constrain(ArrayFormula(If(S3:S&T3:T&U3:U<>"",S3:S+T3:T+U3:U,"")),Countif(A3:A,"<>"),1)
```

For more info see the documentation below.

Array Formulas: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en

Array_Constrain: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

Try adding FILTER to select only the cells that have data? SUM will throw an error if there are no cells left to SUM, and you can catch that error with IFERROR:

=iferror(sum(filter(B2:B5, B2:B5)))

[Demo Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zLQZNaJWKeEC7Xv966mnf0w2PObtn23-fDdhEtxZSpY/edit?usp=sharing)

BTW I may have already built what you're making! I made a Reporting system for my school in Cambodia that pulls the teachers, students, assignments and grades out of Classroom into a bunch of spreadsheets, lets you add comments, then generates pretty PDFs to send to parents with all the data nicely laid out.

[image: PDF demo report front page]
[image: PDF demo report subject page]

The project is on GitHub:

https://github.com/klausrheum/supermarkit

We've been using it for 2.5 years. It's a bit clunky but does the job (basically select actions from a menu in sequence over the course of the semester). If you're already up to speed with AppScript you'd be fine setting it up.